# How can I debug a IE Facebook JS error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk

So, we have a Facebook application that eventually calls https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js.

In Firefox and Chrome, everything seems to work correctly. In IE 8 (with/without compatibility view), I get a Javascript error (syntax error in all.js, line 17, character 864).

Here's that particular code fyi:

```
if(typeof ca==='function')return ca.apply(x,aa);
```

(I see this when I enable debugging in IE and use the internal debugger. I wonder if the '===' is supposed to be '==' insofar as IE is concerned, but perhaps they're both correct expressions.)

So, I don't know Javascript, but I'd like to be able to debug this enough to know if it's a Facebook issue or if it's our issue. (General IE Facebook JS debugging tips are also welcome.)

I should mention that I had to add code to call FB.init in order for the Firefox/Chrome code to work, so perhaps I'm not doing something that IE requires. I'm out of my depth, really, and I'm not even sure what additional information to include.

Comment: It turned out that there was a race condition with IE that had the Javascript from all.js called prior to the FB.init() call. We solved it by wrapping the Javascript that ultimately called all.js into its own function, and then calling that function explicitly after the FB.init() call.

Answer (score 0):

The **==** is a comparison operator with the potential for type conversion.

The **===** is a comparison operator that functions without any conversion (it either is or is not, there is no maybe).

This part of the code looks good. The best thing I can recommend is troubleshooting with the Developer Tools in IE and watching the Script tab. Make sure that "Break on Error" is turned on and follow the call stack back.